# How to make fog in Blender

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I want to create a scene with some fog. I need the fog to get stronger the further form the camera it is. I already have volumetric lights in the scene, but thats not good enough.

[image]

The result should look like that (just... not so... strong?)

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So lets go on buddy...

[image]

...as You could see on the picture above, we have a few steps ahead.

1) **Activate MIST in the Render Layers / Passes** as could bee seen in the center of the image.

2) **Choose the camera and activate MIST in the Camera / Display** section. Now You are able to see the *yellow line* near the camera which shows start and end of the mist.

3) **Now select the values for START and DEPTH in the World / Mist Pass.** The line of the camera will follow accordingly.

4) **Render your image**.

5) Finally, open **Compositor in Node Editor and build the nodes like me** - the important changes are in the *RED rectangle*. The Node I added is the **Add / Color / MIX**.

6) **Render your image AGAIN**.

Hope it helps, buddy - sincerely, Jan

Comment: but the myst kills my volumetrics :(